# Why am I able to remove certain elements using document.getElementsByClassName() but not others?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementsbyclassname, queryselector

I'm trying to create a simple script in ViolentMonkey to run on Letterboxd.com film pages - e.g. https://letterboxd.com/film/mirror/.

I'm aiming to remove certain elements from the page - namely, the average rating and the facebook share buttons.

My script looks like so:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
var rating = document.getElementsByClassName('average-rating')
 $(rating).remove()
 console.log("Rating removed!")
var sidebar = document.getElementsByClassName('panel-share')
 $(sidebar).remove()
 console.log("Panel removed!")
});
```

The element with the class "panel-share" (facebook share buttons) is removed, no problem. However, the element with class "average-rating" is still there.

I tried to instead delete the section-level parent element it like so (it has two classes, "section" and "ratings-histogram-chart):

```
var chart = document.querySelector('.section.ratings-histogram-chart')
$(chart).remove()
console.log("Chart removed!")
```

But still no luck... In fact, querySelector does not work at all.

Can anyone help me with this? I feel I am doing something very obvious wrong, but I am quite new. Many thanks in advance.

EDIT: The HTML on which I'm trying to run it is:

```js
var rating = document.getElementsByClassName('average-rating')
$(rating).remove()
console.log("Rating removed!")
var sidebar = document.getElementsByClassName('panel-share')
$(sidebar).remove()
console.log("Panel removed!");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="average-rating" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating"> <a href="/film/mirror/ratings/" class="tooltip display-rating -highlight" data-original-title="Weighted average of 4.29 based on 35,429&nbsp;ratings">4.3</a> </span>

<li class="panel-share">
  <div id="share-off" style="display: block;"><a href="#">Share</a></div>
  <div id="share-on" style="display: none;"> <input type="text" class="field -transparent" value="https://boxd.it/28Q8" readonly="" spellcheck="false"> <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Mirror%20%281975%29%20on%20%40letterboxd%3A%20https%3A%2F%2Fboxd.it%2F28Q8" class="replace popup-link tw-popup"
      title="Tweet a link">Tweet</a> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=173683136069040&amp;link=https%3A%2F%2Fletterboxd.com%2Ffilm%2Fmirror%2F&amp;picture=https%3A%2F%2Fa.ltrbxd.com%2Fresized%2Ffilm-poster%2F5%2F1%2F0%2F6%2F4%2F51064-mirror-0-230-0-345-crop.jpg%3Fk%3D8287891685&amp;name=Mirror%20%281975%29%20on%20Letterboxd.com&amp;caption=Directed%20by%20Andrei%20Tarkovsky&amp;description=A%20dying%20man%20in%20his%20forties%20recalls%20his%20childhood%2C%20his%20mother%2C%20the%20war%20and%20personal%20moments%20that%20tell%20of%20and%20juxtapose%20pivotal%20moments%20in%20Soviet%20history%20with%20daily%20life.&amp;message=&amp;display=popup&amp;redirect_uri=https://letterboxd.com/facebook-share"
      class="replace popup-link fb-popup fbc-has-badge fbc-UID_1" title="Share to Facebook">Share</a> </div>
</li>
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why are you also using DOM functions? Just write `$(".panel-share").remove()`

Comment: Why are you using jQuery and `querySelector` together?

Comment: If you'd like more help, please provide a sample of the HTML on which the JavaScript provided is to be run. You can use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) to provide a runnable example.

Comment: Hi, I have added the html as requested, thanks for the tip. @HereticMonkey

Comment: @Barmar Unfortunately, it doesn't work for `$(".average-rating").remove()`
Sorry if I am doing things in an unintuitive way, mostly I am learning as I go by reading previous answers on here - my grasp on the theory is bad. I don't code normally, just want to write a simple script for this purpose.

Comment: When I run the snippet above, the `average-rating` DIV is removed.

Comment: The code above works so what is different in your code. How is this code called?

Comment: I'm just pasting the code I wrote at the start directly into a new violentmonkey script with `\\@match *://letterboxd.com/*`. I don't see why it's working for one div and not the other.

Comment: Is the element there when the script runs? `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('panel-share').length);` Debugging is key on trying to find why

Comment: @jinzub I have the answer. i had `myWindow=window.open("https://letterboxd.com/film/mirror/");myWindow.eval(myAnswerBelow)` and you literally see the element disappear before your eyes(as in IT WORKS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here seems to be that the rating graph (incl. the average rating) is loaded asynchronous and thus is not present when your script runs.

In order to counter this, you could listen for changes of the parent  `.sidebar` element and then remove it as soon as it's present:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.panel-share').remove();
  
  // listen for changes of the .sidebar element
  $('.sidebar').on('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
    if($('.average-rating').length) {
      $('.average-rating').remove();
      $(this).off('DOMSubtreeModified');
    }    
  })    
});
``
```

Answer (score 0):

I added 2 sets of listeners, the first one(your own) for when `DOMContentLoaded`, the second one is a quick interval that waits for `document.readyState` to be equal to `"complete"`

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{

  window.n=1 //as extra proof that it works, you can go later and check n on the inspect element's console
  var i=setInterval(() => {
    if(document.readyState!="complete"){window.n++;return;} //once document.readyState=="complete", the rest of the code loads(what you want to execute)
    clearInterval(i)
    console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
    var rating = document.getElementsByClassName('average-rating')
    $(rating).remove()
    console.log("Rating removed!")
    var sidebar = document.getElementsByClassName('panel-share')
    $(sidebar).remove()
    console.log("Panel removed!")
  },1);

})
```

As proof that my answer works, open a new tab/window, navigate to the url https://letterboxd.com/film/mirror/ to avoid cors errors, open inspect element and paste the code below

```
var myWindow=window.open("https://letterboxd.com/film/mirror/")
myWindow.eval(`
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{

  window.n=1 //as extra proof that it works, you can go later and check n on the inspect element's console
  var i=setInterval(() => {
    if(document.readyState!="complete"){window.n++;return;} //once document.readyState=="complete", the rest of the code loads(what you want to execute)
    clearInterval(i)
    console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
    var rating = document.getElementsByClassName('average-rating')
    $(rating).remove()
    console.log("Rating removed!")
    var sidebar = document.getElementsByClassName('panel-share')
    $(sidebar).remove()
    console.log("Panel removed!")
  },1);

})
`)
```